# What is the difference between sAdhAarA diksHA and nirAdhArA diksHA?

Tags: guru, initiation

What is the basic difference between sAdhArA and nirAdhArA diksHA as per the scriptures?

Comment: Diksha with and without adhara.. where did you hear about these?

Comment: But in Tantra books I don't think these are mentioned

Comment: No There is Vedic Diksha .. Mahanirvana Tantram mentions about Pouranic Diksha .. but yes, mostly in today's time, Diksha refers to Tantrik way of Diksha.. I don't think Tantrasara etc mentions about these forms..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one of the comments, you said that Niradhara=without rituals and Sadhara=with rituals.

Then, Sadhara is clearly what is called the KriyAvati DikshA in KulArnava Tantram. Niradhara can be of three types as mentioned below.

In KulArnava Tantram's 14th Chapter, various types of initiations are described. Some of which are based on rituals where as the others are free from any such requirements.

The VAg, Drik and MAnas DikshAs are stated to be performed without any rituals.

> SparshAkhyA devi drik-sangyA mAnasAkhyA maheswari| 
>   KriyAyAs-Adi-rahitA devi dikshA tridhA smritA ||
>
> O Maheswari -- Sparsha DikshA (which is accomplished by the Guru's touch), Drika DikshA (by vision) and
>   MAnasa DikshA (by mind) -- these three are the types of initiations.
>   In these initiations, no rituals and efforts are needed.
>
> **14.34**

The nature of these three types of initiations are briefly given in the following verses:

> YathA pakshi swapakshyAbhyAm shishun samvardhayecchanaih |
>   Sparshdikshopadeshashcha tAdrishah kathithah priye ||
>
> Just like a bird gradually raises up the chicks under it's wings, know
>   the Sparsha DikshA to be of a similar nature, O Beloved.
>
> SwApatyAni yathA matshyo vikshanenaiva poshayet |
>  DrigbhyAm
>   dikshopadeshashcha tAdrishah parameswari ||
>
> O Parameswari, just like a fish raises up it's babies by simply
>   vision, know the DikshA Upadesha called Drik to be of a similar
>   nature.
>
> YathA kurmah swatanayAn dhyAnmAtrena poshayet |
>   Vedhadikshopadeshashcha mAnasah syAt tathAvidhah ||
>
> Just as a tortoise raises it's babies up by simply thinking about them,
>   likewise the Upadesha called Vedha is entirely mental.
>
> **14-35,36,37**

The MAnasa DikshA is also known as Vedha (or Vedhamayi) DikshA.

Now, some DikshA is based on rituals. This is called the KriyAvati DikshA.

> KriyA-varna-kalA-sparsha-vAg-dring-mAnasa-sangyayA |
>  DikshA
>   mokshapradA devi saptadhA parikirtitA ||
>
> KriyA, Varna, KalA, Sparsha, VAk, Drik and MAnasa DikshAs are the
>   seven types of initiations that bestow Moksha, O Devi.
>
> **14.39**

Among, these 7 types, KriyA which requires rituals, is again of 8 types:

> KriyAdikshAshtadhA proktA kunda-mandapa-purvikA |
>   KalashAdisamAyuktA kartyavyA gurunA vahihi ||
>
> The KriyAdikshA is again of eight types. In these initiations, Kunda
>   (fire-pit in which Homa oblations are poured), Mandapa (canopy),
>   Kalasa (a pot) etc are required. The Guru using the above means performs the
>   (external) rituals.
>
> **14.41**

Comment: but the concept of raising tortoise babies seems incorrect as no reptile baby depends on mother

Comment: They seem to be born even if their mother is no longer alive

Comment: Yes, I don't know whether such things actually occur in nature or not :D @Pratimaputra